# backbone relational not updating

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-relational

I have a relationship setup between my user object and my usergame object.
The relationship appears to be setup correctly, i can access usergames through a user object.

However, when I create a new usergame object, the user object does not update.

Could someone offer me a solution to this?

Relationship is setup like so:

```
class App.Models.User extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  urlRoot: '/user'

  relations: [
    type: Backbone.HasMany
    key: 'user_games'
    relatedModel: 'App.Models.UserGame'
    includeInJSON: true
    collectionType: 'App.Collections.UserGames'
    reverseRelation:
      key: 'user'
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational#known-problems-and-solutions):

> **Q**: (Reverse) relations or submodels don't seem to be initialized
>   properly (and I'm using CoffeeScript!)
>
> **A**: You're probably using the syntax `class MyModel extends
>   Backbone.RelationalModel` instead of `MyModel =
>   Backbone.RelationalModel.extend`. This has advantages in CoffeeScript,
>   but it also means that `Backbone.Model.extend` will not get called.
>   Instead, CoffeeScript generates piece of code that would normally
>   achieve roughly the same. However, extend is also the method that
>   Backbone-relational overrides to set up relations and other things as
>   you're defining your `Backbone.RelationalModel` subclass.

That’s a shame, as I like Coffeescript’s `extend` syntax. Try it without, as explained in the documentation?